# Teradata fastload fails when pyspark dataframe has more than one partition

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, teradata, azure-databricks

I am trying to write a spark dataframe into teradata using **FASTLOAD**. The write operation works if I force the dataframe to have only one partition by using `df_final = df_final.repartition(1)`. But, fails if there are more than one partition. Since the data size is huge if repartitioned(1) is applied on the dataframe it will be overhead on the master node. I even tried to match partitions with # of sessions it didn't work.

```
    df_final.write.option("truncate",truncate)\
    .mode(mode).option("batchsize",100000)\
    .jdbc(url="jdbc:teradata://host/DBS_PORT=port,LOGMECH=TD2,TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF16,ENCRYPTDATA=ON,TYPE=FASTLOAD,SESSIONS=2,ERROR_TABLE_DATABASE=errortble",
    table="tempdb.temptable",
    properties=connectionProperties)
```

Teradata Version:16.20.53.04 
JDBC Version: 17.00.00.03

Stack Trace:

```
2022-01-13 15:58:04.701899: Loading data into tempdb.temptable with write mode as overwrite and truncate as true
An error occurred while calling o1002.jdbc.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 31, X.X.X.X, executor 0): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 1154] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while inserting the batch of rows destined for database table "TempDB"."temptable". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:149)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:133)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:691)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1(JdbcUtils.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1001)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1001)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2379)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 1147] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception chain occurred while beginning FastLoad of database table "TempDB"."temptable"
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:95)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:70)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.beginFastLoad(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:966)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2210)
    ... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2519)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2466)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2668)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2656)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2339)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2360)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2379)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2404)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(RDD.scala:1001)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.saveTable(JdbcUtils.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$3(SparkPlan.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:827)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 1154] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while inserting the batch of rows destined for database table "TempDB"."temptable". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:149)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:133)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:691)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1(JdbcUtils.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1001)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1001)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2379)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 1147] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception chain occurred while beginning FastLoad of database table "TempDB"."temptable"
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:95)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:70)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.beginFastLoad(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:966)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2210)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Have you looked in your fastload error table?

Comment: It doesn't log anything into the error table at all.

Comment: @pkatta did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably attempting to initiate multiple FastLoad operations simultaneously into the same destination table, which is not permitted by the database.

The exception stack trace that you posted does not include the entire SQLException chain that is available from the SQLException.getNextException method.

You are using Teradata JDBC Driver 17.00.00.03. In Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10, we have added the FLATTEN=ON connection parameter to combine the SQLException chain from a JDBC FastLoad operation into the top-level thrown SQLException.

Upgrade to the latest Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10 version, specify the FLATTEN=ON connection parameter, and you should be able to see the root cause error from the database.

Comment: Wow, this `FLATTEN=ON` parameter is the best news I have had at least all day, I hated working back through all those getNextExceptions.  I assume 17.10 is backwards compatible through at least v16?

Comment: Yes, Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10 is supported for use with the current plus back 4 database releases, i.e. Teradata SQL Engine 17.10, 17.0, 16.20, 16.10, and 15.10. Our support matrix is available here: https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/platformMatrix.html